# iPhone SDK @selector -> SEL @protocol ->?

Tags: iphone, protocols, selector

okay so I want to make a public function that will return YES if an object exists, conforms to a protocol and responds to a selector. I know the typedef of @selector is SEL but what is the typedef for @protocol

```
BOOL conforms(id object, ? prototype, SEL action) {
  return (object != nil && 
         [object conformsToProtocol:prototype] && 
         [object respondsToSelector:action]);
}
```

And I want to be able to call this function like:

```
if(conforms(delegate, @protocol(UIScrollViewDelegate), 
   @selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:))) {
  [delegate touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [`Protocol`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-TPXREF149) object:

```
BOOL conforms(id object, Protocol *protocol, SEL action) {
  return (object != nil && 
         [object conformsToProtocol:protocol] && 
         [object respondsToSelector:action]);
}
```